# QnA Maker - Updating Knowledge Base

Tags: botframework, azure-qna-maker

My QnA Maker service is currently trained on an excel file I have uploaded. If I update my knowledge base via the QnA maker settings tab and upload a new version of this excel file (deleting the old one), will it overwrite the whole knowledge base? Or just change what I've edited/ added in the file?

[image: Uploading new QnA file]

Furthermore - Will I loose QnA pairs that are 'sitting' in the Train API (As it only pushes to the knowledge base after a number of users send similar feedback)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reply from Qna Maker Team support (12/2/2018):** 
If you upload it on the settings page, 'Files' section, it will not rewrite the entire knowledge base, only the file you reuploaded. It will also retain the training data.
Only 'replace knowledge base' will nuke your training data and Kb.

Answer (score 1):

To add a detailed answer about the files management, in the special case of providing a file via the `Settings` tab of qnamaker.ai, I just made the tests:

- Load a file named "test.xlsx" with 1 line "question;answer1", then `Save and retrain` => the content is in your KB
- Change the content of the file: "question;answer2", go to settings and load directly the file then `Save and retrain` => no changes will be taken into account if you have not removed this file first (looks like a bug yes)
- Do the same but before loading, click on the X to remove the existing "test.xlsx" file, then `Save and retrain` => the changes are taken into account

For the 2nd question:

> Will I loose QnA pairs that are 'sitting' in the Train API (As it only
>   pushes to the knowledge base after a number of users send similar
>   feedback)?

There is no possibility to extract the content of the user feedback so it's impossible to know exactly if thoses changes are lost or not

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test this. Maybe this bug should be reported? With regards to the Train data, it seems you are guessing just as I was, so I emailed QnA Maker Support and got a reply (posted as answer).

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that uploading a knowledge base overwrites the existing QnA pairs in the previous KB:
https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/UpdateKb

I think the best practice and solution for your case is download the KB as a file from the web application, update the file and finally, re upload the file with your changes on top. During this process you might want to stop the service or prevent Active Learning. Otherwise, you will have conflicts between your manual changes and the online KB.

Regards,
Francisco

Comment: Sorry maybe my question wasn't clear enough, your suggestion solution is what I want to do. My knowledge base is trained on a excel file and I am asking if I update and the file and re upload will this overwrite the KB or just update? And how will it affect anything already sent to the Train API

Comment: @kmak did you at least opened the link provided by Fracisco? There is a huge sentence written, saying "[!WARNING] Uploading a knowledge base overwrites the existing QnAs in the knowledge base."

Comment: @NicolasR Yes I had already read it before and it doesn't provide the specific answer to my question - hence coming to Stack Overflow. Yes it states uploading a knowledge base overwrites, however I am uploading a file source, not the knowledge base itself.

Comment: Ok, wasn't clear as you were initially talking about sending again your KB. I added an answer with the corresponding tests

Comment: I was always talking about uploading a file via settings tab, not replacing KB. But thanks for taking the time to do the tests